# How can I get the IP from GraphQL client in resolvers?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am using the GraphQL Yoga (GraphQL implementation).

I tried to follow the approach of this post, however, in addition to being a different implementation it did not work:
https://v1.prisma.io/forum/t/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-the-client/4429
I get the follow error: https://prnt.sc/s4aujd

I am using this architecture as the basis for my project:
https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-yoga/tree/master/examples/mongodb

Comment: nothing different - context fn method should work

Comment: Sorry if I didn't give you enough information. I added a printout of the error to the response. https://prnt.sc/s4aujd

Comment: show your current code ... `const server = new GraphQLServer({.....` ?

Comment: I am using the same base of the implementation that I passed in the link above, but I have no problem passing you the current code in view of what you asked for. https://pastebin.com/GxSBmTAT

Comment: code not used not works? .... where is ` context: context => ({. ....` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. Like I said I used a ready-made GraphQL implementation and I don't know how things should really work. If you believe that this will solve the problem, I would be sure to write an answer so that I can mark it as the best.

Comment: how you can write that sth doesn't work when not tested? just use code from https://v1.prisma.io/forum/t/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-the-client/4429/6 in your config

Comment: I had not seen that the context implementation is different from mine and what it was called. Well, I ran the code here and didn't get any value for the "userip" variable that I called for resolvers. Only null. Here is the code for the relevant files. https://pastebin.com/uuhRqjj7

Comment: Pay attention to the end of the file. I needed to change the code to remove the ?string because it is not compatible with the implementation of the babel I am using.

Comment: you can pass entore request (or headers only) into context (`request: context.request....` ) and explore other `context.request.headers` props - x-forwarded... is not always set

Comment: It seems that now I got a more interesting result! But I'm still a little confused.

I did what you said. This is the console.log of some requests I made. First in the postman, then using GraphQL playground and finally, using pure javascript. I still can't detect the IP, as you mentioned. https://pastebin.com/K50MtdEn

Comment: it depends on env - deploy it somewhere, more real